# Check if Picturebox touches any object on screen C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem with my game that is coded on C#. I've tried searching all over the forums for this problem but none has worked for this case :/

I'm trying to check if Picturebox hits ANY other Picturebox in screen.

I've tried this, but this might be too slow when I add more objects.

```
if (!square.Bounds.IntersectsWith(grass.Bounds) && !square.Bounds.IntersectsWith(grMiddle.Bounds) && !square.Bounds.IntersectsWith(grRight.Bounds) && !square.Bounds.IntersectsWith(middle.Bounds) && !square.Bounds.IntersectsWith(sideRight.Bounds) && !square.Bounds.IntersectsWith(topPanel.Bounds))
```

This method doesn't work since player movement increases 100x and I die instantly, somehow...

```
foreach (PictureBox pic in this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>())
        {
            if (pic != square)  // exclude square PictureBox from the test
            {
                if (!square.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pic.Bounds))
                {
                    if (!square.Bounds.IntersectsWith(rightGoal.Bounds))
                    {
                        if (Right) { square.Left += 5; }
                        if (Left) { square.Left -= 5; }
                        if (Up) { square.Top -= 5; }
                        if (Down) { square.Top += 5; }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pally.points++;
                        rightPoints.Text = pally.points.ToString();
                        square.Location = new Point(690, 533);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    square.Location = new Point(690, 533);
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm out of ideas, some help would be nice :)

Comment: *...but this might be too slow when I add more objects*. Have you time measured the comparison? Comparing 10 or 100 or even 1000 objects is a trivial thing.

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε It probably will be trivial, but I always try to fetch the best methods to perform tasks :)

Comment: The best method is one that is easy to implement, easy to read and easy to extend. Looping through all pic boxes is pretty straight forward. If and only if speed is an issue then you start looking for other solutions. They are going to be more complicated but their speed will compansate that.

Answer (score 2):

```
                    if (Right) { square.Left += 5; }
                    if (Left) { square.Left -= 5; }
                    if (Up) { square.Top -= 5; }
                    if (Down) { square.Top += 5; }
```

Are these testing keyboard inputs or something? You're moving your square with this code. And you're doing it for *each* picturebox on your form. That's why your square moves too far. Separating your position updating code from your intersection code should solve your problem.

Comment: I have done that and it fixed the problem. The best way was just to make a couple of 'if' statements to check the collision as stated in the comments and have the movement elsewhere in the code. Thanks for the reply!